# JSON: filter matching values from array

Tags: json, node.js, object, express

How I can match every articles object which are containing the matching values from the "tags" array, for example if I want to only list the articles which containing "foo" and "bar" keywords?

```
[
  {
    "articles": [
      {
        "_id": "0",
        "body": "This is a test article 1.",
        "tags": [ "foo", "bar" ]
      },
      {
        "_id": "2",
        "body": "This is a test article 2.",
        "tags": [ "baz", "bam" ]
      },
      {
        "_id": "4",
        "body": "This is a test article 4.",
        "tags": [ "foo", "bar", "baz", "bam" ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is the router in my Express app which is calling this JSON file:

```
router.get('/:tag', function (req, res, next) {
  fsAsync(function(err, data) {
    var articles = data[0].articles.reverse();

    var q = articles.filter(function (article) {
      return article.tags === req.params.tag;
    });

    var json = [{ articles: q }];

    // I want the results here
    console.log(json);

    res.render('blog-tag', {
      layout: 'main',
      data: json
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the tag is in the array.

```
var q = articles.filter(function (article) {
  var tagInArray = false;
  article.tags.forEach(function(tag){
      if(tag === req.params.tag){
         tagInArray = true;
      }
  });
  return tagInArray;
});
```

IndexOf

Answer (score 0):

Tags are in Array

```
 var q = articles.filter(function (article) {
 for (var i = 0;i<article.tags.length;i++){
 if(article.tags[i] === req.params.tag)
 return article.tags === req.params.tag;
 }
});
```

Comment: This code seems more simple, but unfortunately not working for me. Returning only `[]` in the console. :(